# How can I shift elements in a non-square matrix

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, transformation

Suppose I have the following non-square 4x3 binary matrix:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

I can shift the non-zero columns of A to the right as follows:

$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$

Is there a shift matrix **X** (or similar object) such that non-zero entries are shifted one column to the right and up one row, producing:

$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}X=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 3):

Pre-multiply $\begin{bmatrix}  0  & 1  & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}  $ on both sides, we can see that the LHS is zero but the RHS is non-zero. Hence no such $X$ exist.

For shifting row up, consider pre-multiplication as well.

Comment: Is there an intuitive explanation for why it is possible to shift the columns as above, but not possible to shift the rows of such matrices (or both rows and columns together)?

Comment: post-multiplication corresponds to linear combination of columsn while pre-multiplication correspodns to rows. That is for matrix-vector multiplication, we have $Av= \sum_{j=1}^n A_n v_n$.